# How can I compile libpoppler-qt with Nokia's Qt SDK

Tags: macos, qt, configure, poppler

Morning !

I would like to compile libpoppler and libpoppler-qt4 (the Qt Api/bindings) with the Nokia's mac sdk available on the website.
I've tried a lots of configure switch but it does not works.
Any hint ?

Comment: In what way does it not work? I downloaded the poppler source tarball and it configured okay for me with no extra arguments on my Linux box.

Comment: because of Mac's Framework system ? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, found the solution : I have to use cmake:

```
tar xvzf poppler-0.14.0.tar.gz
cd poppler-0.14.0
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ../
```

For the libiconv problem, I just edited the CMakefileLists.txt to link with macport's iconv rather than macos one.